# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError assigning value to array in subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, input, lifecycle, subscribe

I've seen hundreds of forums searching for this error, but I havent been able to find the appropriate answer, I'm relatively new on Angular and still cannot understand the thing about lifecycle hooks.

I have a Parent Window who have a component, in this component I'm setting the value of the window

```
<app-acciones [window]="selectedWindow"></app-acciones>
```

In the child I have the input of this window, and an array where I want to assing the value of function I want to subscribe.

```
   @Input() window:Window;
   Actions:Action[];
   totalActions:number; //this work properly
```

And then the method

```
getActionts(){
   this._actionService.getAction(this.window)
   .subscribe(
      actions => {
       this.totalActions = actions.total; // this works
       this.Actions = actions.actions; // this give me the error
     }
   );
}

ngOnChanges(){
   this.getActionts();
}
```

I do not understand why this happens and how to solve it, I would appreciate any help, since although the code is working "correctly" it is very annoying and frustrating not knowing why this happen and how to solve this error.

Comment: this can happen if you call a method from your template that modifies a variable everytime its called and the variable is also bound in your template. bound variables need to stabilize after one VM turn, otherwise you'll get this error

Comment: How I could stabilize the variable in this case?, I understand I should invoque the function in other cycle diferent to the ngOnChanges, but I'm not sure why It doest work, obviously I'm skipping something important, but I can't see what it is

Answer (score 0):

I look that with each change, you are creating a new subscription. You should change and instead of ngChanges, you could use afterViewinit or afterContentInit. 
Even you could create one kind of Observable variable in order to pass directly the Observable to the view and using pipe async to manage the subscription and unsubscription automatically.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I know I may change the ngChanges but for some reason (something I can't see for my low knowlegde), that doest work with the afterViewInit either with the afterContentInit (I had tried previosly), what is the better way to do your suggestion?. How could I implement what you said?